# getting some values in the table view rows in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

hii every one

i am new to iphone, i have done a sample data entry project in that i am saving data into the sqlite then displaying the saved data in the table view , & then on click of each row of the table it will go to other page (grouped table view where i am displying detailed data) now i have the table view like this 
[image: screen shot]

on click of each row it will go to detailed view like this

[image: Screen shot]

then on click of back button it ill come back to data list  screen but it ill add some other data into the screen like this

[image]

i am using reload data in view will apear ,, is that causing this problem?it works fine  if i comment that n try,,

can any one help me

thanx in advance

Comment: How are you getting/setting data for the details screen?

Comment: I want to implement the same in my project, but I am unable to do it. Will u help me how ot implement this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add new row in the table upon back button press, you can either add a new row in the table using

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

or update your array (adding this extra row) with the help of which you show the rows and then reload the table view. Because when you reload your table view, its datasource methods will be called again and then you need to return updated number of sections, rows and cell's

Comment: hii thanx for ur reply,, actually i am not adding any rows while coming back, i just need to come back to the page which contains my original values(with out any garbage values in the table rows like 22 in the snap shot)

Comment: You mean you just cannot get back to your previous page? If you are using navigation controller, as i can see from the screen shots, then upon back button click, say [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; Also please post some code so that we understand

Comment: As you have mentioned, when you come back to the table view, its viewWillAppear function will get called where you are reloading the table view. In this case, try to see how many rows your table view datasource returns. This could help you debug your problem. Also, If there is no need, then dont reload table in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Debug your app. And see your array values in cellForRowAtIndexPath if you have values different then just use [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] in didSelect delegate

Answer (score 0):

Check your array values in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate whether you have different arrays or not.

If yes then use `[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`